# Storage REST API Returns Remote Name Could Not be Resolve Often

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rest-api

I am calling the storage REST API to get container names using

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $storage_url -Headers $headers
```

This command often returns 'remote name could not be resolved error', even when the storage account exists and is reachable. Just running the command again gives correct result.

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote name could not be resolved: '<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net'
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $storage_url -Headers $headers #In ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: why do you think it has something to do with Azure?

Comment: Which api did you use? Which auth way did you use? Could you include more details about the request? Include the request url and headers?

Comment: API version being used- 2017-11-09; URL- https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list; 
Auth- AAD bearer token using URL login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token and body- 
client_id:<clientId>
client_secret:<client app secret>
resource:https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net
grant_type:client_credentials
; and headers- x-ms-date, x-ms-version and Authorization = 'Bearer <bearer token>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you provided, you use the client credential flow to get the access token, then use the token to call the [`Storage Rest API - List Containers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2).

You could use the script below, it works for me.

Make sure the service principal you used has a RBAC role e.g. `Contributor/Owner` in your storage account -> `Access Control`, if  not, click the `Add` to add it.

[image]

```
$ClientID       = "xxxxxxx" 
$ClientSecret   = "xxxxxxx"  
$tennantid      = "xxxxxxx"
$storageaccountname = "joystoragev2"

$TokenEndpoint = {https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token} -f $tennantid 
$Resource = "https://storage.azure.com/"

$Body = @{
        'resource'= $Resource
        'client_id' = $ClientID
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
    Body = $Body
    Method = 'Post'
    URI = $TokenEndpoint
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$accesstoken = $token.access_token

$url = {https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list} -f $storageaccountname

$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
    'x-ms-version' = '2019-02-02'
}

$response = Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url –Headers $header –Method GET

$response.RawContent
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much Joy :) I am using the exact same script with two differences- 1. added the client app as 'Storage Blob Data Reader' instead of Owner to the storage account so that it gets only blob reader access and not write access + used the resource as 'https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net' instead 'https://storage.azure.com/' again for restricted access.. but let me try with the version you used- '2019-02-02' as i was using '2017-11-09' .. maybe the issue got fixed in later versions

Comment: @user2848940 Also make sure you turned off the firewall of the storage account.

Comment: yeap firewall is turned off and this api works better.. ill be using the latest api- 2019-07-07